# How to add tool to open Git shell in repository from msysgit (GUI)?

Tags: git, msysgit, git-gui

Is there a quick command that I can put in so that if I run this tool it will open a shell which is set to the repo's directory?  I have searched everywhere and it seems I cannot find a command that will work!

[image]

**Answer**

I finally found out how to do it:

`cmd /c cd %v & start "" "C:\path\to\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`

The reason why you have to pass an empty argument to the `start` command is because the first argument in quotes gets set as the window title.  So, if you want to name your window, do this:

`cmd /c cd %v & start "WINDOW TITLE HERE" "C:\path\to\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`

*Command explanation*

- `cmd /c cd %v` - Changes your current directory to the path of the repo.
- `start "WINDOW TITLE HERE" "C:\path\to\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` - Starts up your shell, setting the window to `WINDOW TITLE HERE`, and passing `--login -i` to the executable `sh.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this

```sh
cmd /c cd %v & start C:/path/to/bin/bash -il
```

[`ref`](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.cygwin)

Comment: So, after your answer, it led me to a very similar command: `cmd /c cd %v & start "" "C:\path\to\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`  Thank you!